# Reference to a int, or other valuetype

Tags: c#

At startup I read some big data into a dictionary. Then in the processing part the values will change plenty of times. The problem is that looking up the dictionary index every time takes to long. And I can't use the 'unsafe' to get access to pointers.

So I would be able to do something like;

```
int dGeoLocationNorth = rawDataStore["GeoLoc_AC_154"]; // Raw data store is a custom implementation of a dict which is optimized
Console.WriteLine(dGeoLocatioNorth); // Output: 295
Console.WriteLine(rawDataStore["GeoLoc_AC_154"]); // Output: 295
dGeoLocationNorth = 1337;
Console.WriteLine(dGeoLocatioNorth); // Output: 1337
Console.WriteLine(rawDataStore["GeoLoc_AC_154"]); // Output: 1337
```

Any ideas for how I can achive this?

Comment: How many values are you storing?  What type of values are you storing in the dictionary?  How are you defining "too long?"

Comment: What is you custom dictionary optimized for if index look up takes too long?

Comment: The Dictionary class implementation has an amortized bounds of O(1) for insert/update/fetch/delete *by key* and it's a "pretty small C". While a hash-based dictionary is not always sufficient (or rather, not always ideal), if there is a doubt over performance, make sure to supply an actual problem case for a better response.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class to wrap your values and store those objects in your dictionary.

```
var dGeoLocationNorth = rawDataStore["GeoLoc_AC_154"]; // Raw data store is a custom implementation of a dict which is optimized
Console.WriteLine(dGeoLocatioNorth.Value); // Output: 295
Console.WriteLine(rawDataStore["GeoLoc_AC_154"].Value); // Output: 295
dGeoLocationNorth.Value = 1337;
Console.WriteLine(dGeoLocatioNorth.Value); // Output: 1337
Console.WriteLine(rawDataStore["GeoLoc_AC_154"].Value); // Output: 1337
```

It's not too tidy, but it should work.